# How to do popup with inactive and active background when mouse/cursor click out of popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have button on HTML page. When I click on it, I display a popup. When I do that I need to disable the background or gray out background except the popup I have opened. When mouse/cursor clicks out of this popup, everything should come to normal (enable everything) and popup closes.

I am using below code:

```
<a href="#" id="showModal" class="btn btn-success"  ><i class="icon-map-marker" style="color: #fff;"></i>&nbsp;Select Region</a>

<script type="text/javascript">


        window.onload = function() {

            var modal = new RModal(document.getElementById('modal'), {
                //content: 'Abracadabra'
                beforeOpen: function(next) {
                    console.log('beforeOpen');
                    next();
                }
                , afterOpen: function() {
                    console.log('opened');
                }

                , beforeClose: function(next) {
                    console.log('beforeClose');
                    next();
                }
                , afterClose: function() {
                    console.log('closed');
                }
                // , bodyClass: 'modal-open'
                // , dialogClass: 'modal-dialog modal-dialog-lg'
                // , dialogOpenClass: 'animated fadeIn'
                // , dialogCloseClass: 'animated fadeOut'

                // , focus: true
                // , focusElements: ['input.form-control', 'textarea', 'button.btn-primary']

                // , escapeClose: true
            });

            document.addEventListener('keydown', function(ev) {
                modal.keydown(ev);
            }, false);

            document.getElementById('showModal').addEventListener("click", function(ev) {
                ev.preventDefault();
                modal.open();
            }, false);

           window.modal = modal;
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Absolutely position the popup to take the entire page and give it ablack background with less that 1 opacity, so you get the see-through effect. Then add a click handler to the document that checks if the element clicked is a child of the popup element.

Comment: please respond for the query as soon as possible its very urgent.

Comment: hello shilly i can't get your answr can you plz send the code

Comment: I'm not a contracter of your firm, just wanted to help by stating how I'd solve the issue.

Comment: i am sorry i didnt mean that please help me for the issue

Answer (score 1):

Here is my answer:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


        window.onload = function() {

            var modal = new RModal(document.getElementById('modal'), {
                //content: 'Abracadabra'
                beforeOpen: function(next) {
                    console.log('beforeOpen');
                    next();
                }
                , afterOpen: function() {
                    console.log('opened');
                }

                , beforeClose: function(next) {
                    console.log('beforeClose');
                    next();
                }
                , afterClose: function() {
                    console.log('closed');
                }
                // , bodyClass: 'modal-open'
                // , dialogClass: 'modal-dialog modal-dialog-lg'
                // , dialogOpenClass: 'animated fadeIn'
                // , dialogCloseClass: 'animated fadeOut'

                // , focus: true
                // , focusElements: ['input.form-control', 'textarea', 'button.btn-primary']

                // , escapeClose: true
            });

            document.addEventListener('keydown', function(ev) {
                modal.keydown(ev);
            }, false);

            document.getElementById('showModal').addEventListener("click", function(ev) {
                ev.preventDefault();
                modal.open();
            }, false);

           window.modal = modal;

           document.getElementById('modal').addEventListener("click", function(ev) {
                ev.preventDefault();
                modal.close();
            }, false);

            document.getElementsByClassName("modal-content")[0].addEventListener("click", function(ev) {
                ev.preventDefault();
                ev.stopPropagation();

            }, false);
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: i have a one more query...for the same code above mentioned can you please help me to solve..  on pageload popup will display when i clicked on the page including popup  page wont be enabled

Comment: If it works for you first accept my answer :) 
So, now you want to hide page behind popup (modal) on page load and then you want normal behavior ? right

Comment: Try this example mate
http://plnkr.co/edit/mCjv9UPR3cuPnGzo0GZP?p=preview

Comment: user3273700 thank you so much thanks alot...its working awesome...tqq

Comment: You're welcome. You can add comment hare i will reply

Comment: user3273700 you are suggested this popup for onload and click functionality ....plnkr.co/edit/mCjv9UPR3cuPnGzo0GZP?p=preview....but its taking lot of loading time and small isssues are happening in my website can you please suggest some other popup with same functionality

Answer (score 0):

You can bind an `eventListener` to the body each time the modal opens, that calls the modal.close method.

The `afterOpen` method will look like this:

```
afterOpen: function() {
   console.log('opened');
   document.body.addEventListener("click", closeModal, false);
}
```

Then the `closeModal` function has to unsubscribe from the `body.click` event:

```
function closeModal(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  modal.close();
  document.body.removeEventListener('click', closeModal, false);
}
```

Comment: This will close the modal when the user clicks inside it as well.

Comment: yea, you're right! `stopPropagation` on the modal would solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I've never worked with RModal, so I don't know its API.
You can reverse engineer this basic example:

The important part is using `node.contains()` to check if the item clicked on is outside the modal, else you'll hide the modal on every click. The css is just there to give you the blackened background effect.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style>
        #wrapper {
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
        }
        #wrapper.active {
            display: block;
        }
        #popup {
            background-color: red;
            border: 1px solid black;
            margin: 20% auto;
            padding: 20px;
            width: 20%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<button>show popup</button>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="popup">POPUP</div>
</div>
<script>
var wrapper = document.querySelector('#wrapper'),
    popup = document.querySelector('#popup'),
    checkHidePopup = function checkHidePopup( event ) {
        if (!popup.contains(event.target)) {
            wrapper.className = '';
            wrapper.removeEventListener('click', checkHidePopup, false);
        }
    };
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function( event ) {
    wrapper.className = 'active';
    wrapper.addEventListener('click', checkHidePopup, false);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```